# Как сделать рассылку в телеграм боте?

Tags: python, бот, telebot, telegram

Написал код, не могу понять, что именно неправильно.

Первая часть кода должна при активации /start записать id пользователя в joined.txt.

Вторая часть кода:

Запускает рассылку текста всем id в joined.txt, если админ прописывает команду /special + текст

```
import telebot
bot = telebot.TeleBot('')
joinedFile = open("joined.txt", "r")
joinedUsers = set ()
for line in joinedFile:
   joinedUsers.add(line.strip())
joinedFile.close()

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def startjoin(message):
   if not str(message.chat.id) in joinedUsers:
      joinedFile = open(joined.txt", "a")
      joinedFile.write(str(message.chat.id) + "\n")
      joinedUsers.add(message.chat.id)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['special'])
def mess(message):
   for user in joinedUsers:
      bot.send_message(user, message.text[message.text.find(' '):])
```

Comment: Выводится какая-то ошибка?

Comment: нет, просто данный код полностью игнорируется

Comment: А если использовать `Newsletter` вместо `special`.

Comment: это же просто название команды, оно ничего не меняет

Comment: Да, точно, а вы уверенны, что в joinedUsers что-то содержится?

Comment: Вам тут даже подсветка кода ошибку выводит, плюс открывайте и закрывайте файлы оператором `with`

Answer (score 1):

Думал, проблема очевидная, вы пропустили кавычку

```
import telebot
bot = telebot.TeleBot('')
joinedFile = open("joined.txt", "r")
joinedUsers = set ()
for line in joinedFile:
   joinedUsers.add(line.strip())
joinedFile.close()

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def startjoin(message):
   if not str(message.chat.id) in joinedUsers:
      joinedFile = open("joined.txt", "a")
      joinedFile.write(str(message.chat.id) + "\n")
      joinedUsers.add(message.chat.id)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['special'])
def mess(message):
   for user in joinedUsers:
      bot.send_message(user, message.text[message.text.find(' '):])
```

Answer (score -2):

- В данном случае бот ищет пользователя из списка joinedUser и пытается
  каждому отправить, но если человек отписался, то он не может этого
  сделать и не отсылает никому сообщения. При отписке пользователя от
  бота нужно удалять его из файла с ID, в коде такого нет.
- Момент второй, при таком коде рассылку может делать любой
  пользователь бота, а не только админ, нужен ID админа и сверять, он
  ли посылает ему команду с рассылкой, если да, то уже идти по списку с
  ID и отправлять сообщения.

*Сам только с этой проблемой разбираюсь, может ты уже решил эту проблему - буду рад услышать ответ ))*

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «[задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)» в правом верхнем углу страницы; если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос. а этот «ответ» пожалуйста удалите.